# reload php generated table without page refresh

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm making a table in HTML which gets generated via PHP code:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>#</td>
      <td>name</td>
      <td>specie</td>
      <td>client</td>
      <td>status</td>
      <td>action</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <body>
    <?php
      foreach($sortedPatients as $patient){
        echo "<tr><td>" . $patient['patient_id'] . "</td><td>" . $patient['patient_name'] . "</td>";
        foreach($species as $specie){
          if($specie['species_id'] == $patient['species_id']){
            echo "<td>" . $specie['species_description'] . "</td>";
          }
        }
        foreach($clients as $client){
          if($client['client_id'] == $patient['client_id']){
            echo "<td>" . $client['client_firstname'] . $client['client_lastname'] . "</td>";
          }
        }
        echo "<td>" . $patient['patient_status'] . "</td><td><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil icon'></i><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash icon'></i></td></tr>";
      }
    ?>
  </body>
</table>
```

This completely works but now I change the data ($sortedPatients) and the table won't change. Is there a way to update this table so it will show the new data?

I tried using jQuery to load the table from a different file and use JavaScript setInterval to do this every second. But then it didn't want to receive the data in the sub file that was loaded in the main file

Comment: Your last statement is not clear at all. If you need to update a table without reloading you need to use AJAX. jQuery does Ajax well

Comment: @mplungjan can you tell me a bit more on how i should do this? i have never used ajax and i dont know what to look for.

Comment: Search here at SO for _[php][jquery] ajax  table_

Answer (score 1):

The answer here is that there is no way for you to refresh the page using PHP without reloading the page. You will need to use JavaScript or one of it's frameworks to manipulate the DOM. JQuery is an OK way of accomplishing this.

You can do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "yourscript.php",
  data: params,
  success: function(response) {
    // Do stuff with the JSON data to update your table.
    // Since you don't have classes / ids in your html rows or columns,
    // You can do something like $('tbody').html(""); to clear all of 
    // tBody children and then rebuild your table in JavaScript.
    // This is messy and there are better ways of handling this.
  },
  error: function(errors) {
    console.log(errors);
  }
});
```

Another thing you could do is learn a Data Model Binding JS framework like Vue, Knockout, React, or Angular. For something simple like what you are trying to accomplish Vue would be the fastest and easiest to learn.

Take a look at these examples [weblesson](http://www.webslesson.info/2016/02/live-table-add-edit-delete-using-ajax-jquery-in-php-mysql.html) and [itsolutionstuff](https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/simple-php-jquery-ajax-crudinsert-update-delete-tutorial-example-with-source-codeexample.html).

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: yes. i did edit your post a bit but i got it to work. thanks again!